# I want share data between two component that are unrelated to each other

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

here is my folder structure
Top-nav
Side-nav

screen having selector of top and side nav, and I want to pass title from side nav to top nav

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your project there can be various options.

1. If this is your pet project and nothing big, then you can hold data in the parent component(that holds both Top nav and Side nav).
2. If this is a medium-scale project which does not involve much sophistication, then data can be shared via any service, since services are singleton data sharing should be a piece of cake.
3. If this is a big company project and no boundary to libraries being added, then you can use NgRx or any other proper state management library(as suggested by @Filip Huhta above)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/guide/store) `service` to pass values between `components` that are not related to eachother. Look at the examples in **NgRx doc** which are explained really well.